# SFML with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, sfml

I've been trying to set up SFML with Code::Blocks, but there seems to be quite a problem. There are many threads about SFML with Code::Blocks, and many of them have solutions, but none of them seem to work for me.

I use Code:::Blocks 16.01 - 32 bit. On the starting page of Code::Blocks it says "Release 16.01 rev 10702 (2016-01-25 19:50:14) gcc 4.9.2 Windows/unicode - 32 bit ", if that's important.

I use SFML 2.4.2 MinGW, but whenever I try to build my code I get this message:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\johwes16\Desktop\SFML-2.4.2 MinGW32\lib\libsfml-graphics-s.a(CircleShape.cpp.obj):CircleShape.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
C:\Users\johwes16\Desktop\SFML-2.4.2 MinGW32\lib\libsfml-graphics-s.a(CircleShape.cpp.obj):CircleShape.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD0Ev[__ZN2sf11CircleShapeD0Ev]+0x24)||undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

This is the tutorial I use: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php

I've also tried to compile SFML myself using CMake,configuring it to MinGW Makefiles, but it doesn't work either. I can share the logs but I dont know where to upload them.

I've tried on two different computers and have gotten the same problem.

EDIT: I use the same code as the one in the tutorial.

Comment: Are you certain you downloaded and are using the "GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit" version of SFML? The SFML version has to match exactly with your compiler.